# Vosk не распознает речь (Python)

Tags: python, wav, pyaudio, vosk

При попытке открыть базовый пример:

```
from vosk import Model, KaldiRecognizer
import os
import pyaudio

model = Model(r"model")
rec = KaldiRecognizer(model, 8000)
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(
    format=pyaudio.paInt16, 
    channels=1, 
    rate=8000, 
    input=True, 
    frames_per_buffer=8000
)
stream.start_stream()

while True:
    data = stream.read(4000)
    if len(data) == 0:
        break

    print(rec.Result() if rec.AcceptWaveform(data) else rec.PartialResult())

print(rec.FinalResult())
```

Выводится ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\Desktop\vosk-model-small-en-us-0.15\v.py", line 22, in <module>
    print(rec.Result() if rec.AcceptWaveform(data) else rec.PartialResult())
  File "C:\Users\Ruslan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\vosk\__init__.py", line 78, in AcceptWaveform
    raise Exception("Failed to process waveform")
Exception: Failed to process waveform
```

В чем проблема? В интернете найти так ничего и не смог

Comment: Формат может не тот. Или клади буфера побольше